# How do I take a list of lists and rearrange them in python

Tags: python, list

I am trying to create a function that can do this.

```
>>> rearrange_list([1,2,3],[4,5,6])
[[1,4],[2,5],[3,6]]
```

So far what I have is

```
def rearrange_list(my_list):
    i = 0
    n = 0
    new_list = []
    for i in range(0, len(my_list[n])):
        for n in range(0,len(my_list)):
            new_list += [my_list[n][i]]
            print(new_list)
            n += 1
    return new_list
```

but this code returns `[1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 6]`, a single list instead of
a list of lists like I want it to and I can't seem to figure out how to make the
function output a list of lists based on the index of the list inside the list.

Comment: `zip` should do what you want. Although it gives you a list of tuples, not lists.

Comment: Is there a way I can change the tuples into a list? I need it specifically to be a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `zip()` instead:

```
>>> zip([1,2,3], [4,5,6])
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
```

or, for your specific varargs version:

```
>>> lsts = ([1,2,3], [4,5,6])
>>> zip(*lsts)
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
```

or map the results to lists if tuples won't do:

```
map(list, zip([1,2,3], [4,5,6]))  # Python 2
[list(t) for t in zip([1,2,3], [4,5,6])]  # Python 2 and 3
```

As a replacement for your function:

```
def rearrange_list(*my_lists):
    return [list(t) for t in zip(*my_lists)]
```

Comment: I seem to have some trouble with the last bit https://eval.in/669542. Why is there not output?

Comment: @biogeek: because you are not printing anything. `eval.in` is not the Python interactive interpreter, nothing is echoed. Add a `print()` call.

Comment: Hmm..but it does not rearrange the elements like it does in the other data.  Shouldn't it read like `list2 = [['AAAA','DDDD','GGGG','JJJJ'],['BBBB','EEEE','HHHH','KKKK'],['CCCC','FFFF','IIII','LLLL']]`

Answer (score 1):

Use zip like so:

```
zip(list_a, list_b)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#zip) and a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> def rearrange_lists(a, b):
...     return [list(x) for x in zip(a, b)]
...
>>> rearrange_lists([1,2,3], [4,5,6])
[[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6]]
>>>
```

---

Note that the above function only handles two lists.  If you want to handle any number of lists, you can use this:

```
>>> def rearrange_lists(*lsts):
...     return [list(x) for x in zip(*lsts)]
...
>>> rearrange_lists([1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9])
[[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]
>>>
```

Comment: @agconti - More efficient than what?  If you mean the OP's current code, then yes, it is far more efficient.  The built-in functions run a lot faster than custom ones (well, I'll say 99% of the time in case there is any freak examples I don't know about ;).  Plus, my solution uses a list comprehension, which are almost always faster than for-loops.